# C++ Changing owned object type in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

We have four classes: A, B, X, and Y.  B inherits from A and Y inherits from X. Each instance of A creates an owned object of type X.  Some Pseudocode:

```
class A {
    protected:
        X * OwnedObject;
}

class B : public A {
    B();
    void BFunction();
};

B::B() {
    OwnedObject = new Y();
}

B::BFunction() {
    OwnedObject -> YFunction(); //error, class A has no member named 'YFunction()'
}

class X {};

class Y : public X {
    void YFunction(); //this function is new, it is not in X
};
```

B, of course, inherits the pointer to X.  What if we want B to create (and its OwnedObject pointer to point to) an object of child class Y instead of parent class X?  What is the most correct way to approach this problem?

Edit: Sorry if I was unclear, I added some more Pseudocode to illustrate more specifically the problem I'm having and what I want to do. Thanks for the input so far!

Comment: I don't see any code here that "creates an owned object of type `X`".

Comment: Do you need to access Y features (which are not available in the X interface) in B? (Your question doesn't say so. And when you don't, you can just create different objects, for example in the constructors of A and B - see answer of ichramm, and let the X pointer point to the Y object. Which is ok because Y is a sublcass of X)

Comment: Are there any constraints?

Comment: Sebastian: yes, I need to access Y features in B. Uchia: I'm a beginner programmer, I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I think the answer is no :)  as long as the basic structure and logic flow is preserved.

Comment: I've got a hunch that this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+covariant+member+variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two different approaches.

In the first one, I'd assume that class X can know about the functions that its children might change/implement, but it (X) itself doesn't know the exact implementation. In this case, I'd have a `virtual` function in X, and depending on if there is the possibility of instantiating from X or not, have two implementations:

```
// this X can not be instantiated
class X{
    public:
        virtual void f() = 0;
}
class Y : public X{
    public:
        virtual void f() { stuff to do; }
}
```

Or:

```
// this X can be instantiated
class X{
    public:
        virtual void f() { };
}
class Y : public X{
    public:
        virtual void f() { stuff to do; }
}
```

Or in another scenario, I'd assume that because `B` is instantiating from `Y`, then it knows that it's instantiating from `Y`, therefore it can cast it safely to `Y`, whenever it wants to use it:

```
B::BFunction() {
    static_cast<Y*>(OwnedObject) -> YFunction(); 
}
```

Or maybe if you want to be on the safe side:

```
B::BFunction() {
    if (dynamic_cast<Y*>(OwnedObject) != null)
        static_cast<Y*>(OwnedObject) -> YFunction();
}
```

Comment: static_cast after dynamic_cast is redundant.

Comment: And the star is missing for the casts: <Y*>

Comment: If you want to avoid the `static_cast`, you will need an extra variable of the type `T*`, but because `static_cast` is fast (if not zero operation on runtime?), I personally prefer this solution, specially if the function is not going to be called too frequent.
`T` is changed to `T*` now, thanks.

Comment: With the extra variable, the compiler checks for you if you can assign the result of the dynamic_cast. With the static_cast, if you use another type in the two casts by accident, it doesn't. (And with C++11 auto it gets even better).

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this?

```
class A {
protected:
    A(X *x) : OwnedObject(x) {
        // code...
    }

    X * OwnedObject;
}

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A(new Y()) {
        // code...
    }
};
```

I just added to `A` the possibility to inject a `X` object from any child class

Comment: Thanks for the response! That looks like a good solution, but it doesn't work for me in this case. The parameters for the X/Y constructors are extremely complex and are calculated inside the A/B constructors: not the sort of thing I could just inject into the A/B parameters. (Sorry if I should have specified this above, I was trying to keeping the question brief and generalized)

Answer (score 0):

The static_cast solution of adrin is probably the simplest thing you can do.
You just need to be sure that OwndedObject always is an instance of Y (and not X or another subclass of it).

You can check that at runtime (see dynamic_cast in answer of adrin, but use result of dynamic_cast instead of adding another static_cast).

```
B::BFunction() {
    if (Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(OwnedObject))
        y->YFunction();
}
```

Or you can declare the pointer const (the pointer, not the pointee! "const" keyword after the star), and initialize it in the constructor (answer of ichramm). Then, you only need to look at the constructor of A and B in order to reason that your static_cast is safe.

You could configure the type of the OwnedObject by a template. Inspired by this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern.

Or, instead of storing the pointer in your base class, make a virtual member function which provides read access to it:

```
class A_interface {
public:
    virtual X* getX() = 0;
};
class A: public A_interface {
    X* OwnedObject;
public:
    virtual X* getX() {return OwnedObject;}
};
// B is no subclass of A anymore, because you don't want that X* member.
class B: public A_interface {
    Y* OwnedObject;
public:
    virtual X* getX() {return OwnedObject;}
};
```

By desing, you can't have a setX(X*) virtual member function in A_interface, because you couldn't implement that in B. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)